# Samsung Gear 2 unexpected application shutdown

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I have developed (Tizen SDK for Wearable)  a stand alone application involving the inertial sensors (accelerometer and gyroscope) and the heart rate sensor on my Samsung Gear 2.

```
    window.onload = function() {

var logResult = document.getElementById('resultBoard'),
myHeart;

window.webapis.motion.start("HRM", onchangedCB);

    function onchangedCB(hrmInfo) 
    {
       myHeart = hrmInfo.heartRate ;
    }


     function deviceMotionEvent(e) {

        Ax = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x / 9.8;
        Ay = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y / 9.8;
        Az = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z / 9.8;
        Wx = e.rotationRate.alpha;
        Wy = e.rotationRate.beta;
        Wz = e.rotationRate.gamma;

        logResult.innerHTML = Ax+ ' ' + Ay+ ' ' + Az+ ' ' + myHeart;
     }

 window.addEventListener("devicemotion", deviceMotionEvent, true);

 }
```

Systematically after a period of time more or less prolonged (a few seconds or tens of minutes) the application  stops abruptly (any error management embedded in the software doesn't generate any message).
The log generated by the device reports:
WARNING / CRASH_DAEMON ( 227 : 227 ) : worker.c: do_crash_worker(866) > (SWebProcess16751423649750).

Has somebody an idea about the meaning of above message?

The problem disappears by eliminating the collection of the heart rate data.

Comment: What's a line 866 of worker.c?

Comment: Line 866 is not part of my code. Worker.c seems to be a C code module. My appliction is based on a Tizen Web project (HTML5).